# How can i display a list in a grid with 2 columns?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I have an app that creates a list of images. As it is its displayed in one single row, and I feel it could be more efficient putting them in two columns, I tried removing the Stackpanel:

```
            <ListBox
                ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
                SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>

                            <Image Source="{Binding SmallLogoURL}" Height="75" Width="75" Margin="0,0,10,0" />

                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>
```

But I still get it in a single column list :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just load it through a `WrapPanel` as your `ItemsPanelTemplate` like;

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

PS - You can set the `Width` on your `WrapPanel` to reflect the amount of columns you're shooting for since your images already have a fixed size to accomplish just two columns or just leave it to whatever it can fill by itself.

Hope this helps.